# Pandas dataframe to doc2vec.LabeledSentence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word2vec, doc2vec

I have this dataframe :

```
    order_id    product_id  user_id          
    2           33120       u202279  
    2           28985       u202279  
    2           9327        u202279  
    4           39758       u178520  
    4           21351       u178520  
    5           6348        u156122  
    5           40878       u156122
```

Type user_id : String
Type product_id : Integer

I would like to use this dataframe to create a Doc2vec corpus. So, I need to use the LabeledSentence function to create a dict :
 {tags : user_id, words:
all product ids ordered by each user_id}

But the the dataframe shape is (32434489, 3), so I should avoid to use a loop to create my labeledSentence.

I try to run this function (below) with multiprocessing but is too long.

Have you any idea to transform my dataframe in the good format for a Doc2vec corpus where the tag is the user_id and the words is the list of products by user_id?

```
def append_to_sequences(i):
     user_id = liste_user_id.pop(0)
     liste_produit_userID = data.ix[data["user_id"]==user_id, "product_id"].astype(str).tolist()
     return doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=prd_user_list, tags=user_id )

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
result = pool.map_async(append_to_sequences, np.arange(len_liste_unique_user))
pool.close()
pool.join()
sentences = result.get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiprocessing is likely overkill. The forking of processes can wind up duplicating all existing memory, and involve excess communication marshalling results back into the master process.

Using a loop should be OK. 34 million rows (and far fewer unique `user_id`s) isn't that much, depending on your RAM.

Note that in recent versions of gensim `TaggedDocument` is the preferred class for Doc2Vec examples.

If we were to assume you have a list of all unique `user_id`s in `liste_user_id`, and a (new, not shown) function that gets the list-of-words for a `user_id` called `words_for_user()`, creating the documents for Doc2Vec in memory could be as simple as:

```
documents = [TaggedDocument(words=words_for_user(uid), tags=[uid])
             for uid in liste_user_id]
```

Note that `tags` should be a list of tags, not a single tag – even though in many common cases each document only has a single tag. (If you provide a single string tag, it will see `tags` as a list-of-characters, which is not what you want.)